# Expression in query treated as string

Tags: ms-access, expression

I am having a hell of a time trying to add two calculated fields in a query together. My first record has field1= 1, and field2= 5, and the field that is trying to add them as 15! 
So it’s treating them as a string. 
When I try to use the function of SUM() I get an error of some of the other fields not being used in expressions, which I don’t understand. 
Subtracting the two fields works as does multiplication. 
I am unable to change the format of either fields in the properties as the drop down menu is blank. 
Please help!

Comment: Fixed the issue of not being able to change the properties by getting rid of the spaces in the expression names. Still having the other issues though.

Comment: What programming language or tool or application or framework are you talking about?

Comment: Microsoft access query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate functions act on rows not fields. `Sum(field1)` adds the values of field1 for group of records. Use aggregate functions in an aggregate (GROUP BY) query.

Plus (+) character will concatenate text values but add numeric. Apparently, your two fields are providing text values. Either correct the field data type or use function to convert values to number. Convert at least one field and Access will perform arithmetic instead of concatenation on all terms of expression.

`Val(field1) + field2`

This assumes no fields are Null. Number conversion functions will error with Null. Also, arithmetic with Null returns Null. If Null is possibility, handle with Nz().

`Val(Nz(field1,0)) + Nz(field2,0)`

Comment: This worked. Although I used: 'Delay: Val(Nz([field1],0))+Val(Nz([field2],0)). Not because I thought I knew better, but because I messed up transcribing. Worked though! Thanks a bunch!